# How to split string into a Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary, split

I need to create an dictionary by splitting a string like this:

```
[SenderName]
Some name
[SenderEmail]
Some email address
[ElementTemplate]
Some text for
an element
[BodyHtml]
This will contain
the html body text 
in
multi
lines
[BodyText]
This will be multiline for text
body
```

The key could be surrounded by anything if that easier, e.g. [!#key#!]
i'm interested in getting everything within [] into the dictionary as keys and whatever between the “keys” as values:

```
key ::  value
SenderName  ::  Some name
SenderEmail  ::  Some email address
ElementTemplate  ::  Some text for
                     an element
```

Thanks

Comment: Can the values contain '[' and ']'? If so, how are they escaped?

Comment: There's a space before [ElementTemplate] in your example. Is it a glitch or are whitespaces (maybe be even comments) before the [ allowed? Do section identifiers always occupy a whole line?

Comment: VolkerK: The space before [ElementTemplate] is my error - sorry. 
Kent: good point, maybe I don't know. The key could be surrounded by anything if that easier, e.g. [!# key#!]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# 3.0 version -

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> SplitToDictionary(string input)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)");

    return regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().ToDictionary(x => x.Groups[1].Value, x => x.Groups[2].Value.Trim());
}
```

Oneliner of previous version -

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> SplitToDictionary(string input)
{
    return new Regex(@"\[([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)").Matches(input).Cast<Match>().ToDictionary(x => x.Groups[1].Value, x => x.Groups[2].Value.Trim());
}
```

Standard C# 2.0 version -

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> SplitToDictionary(string input)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)");

    Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))
    {
        result.Add(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value.Trim());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your format looks a lot similar like the [Windows INI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) file format. Google gives me [this article](http://bytes.com/topic/net/insights/797169-reading-parsing-ini-file-c) when I searched for "C# ini file parser". You could take some ideas from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first '[' and all the "]\n" for ']'

Then split you string using '[' as escape. At this time you will have an array like

key]value
0 - SenderName]Some name
1 - SenderEmail]Some email address
2 - ElementTemplate]Some text for
                     an element

Then it's easy. Iterate through it, splitting using ']' as escape. The first element is the key, the second one will be the value.